# Resolving CSS url() in WebPack

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am having trouble setting up `url()` resolving in CSS files with WebPack. I have the following directory structure style in the Angular project.

```
dist
src
|_ app
   |_ components
      |_ component
         |_component.html
         |_component.css
|_ public
   |_ img
```

When I build, everything from `public` gets copied to `dist`. E.g. the whole `src/public/img` folder ends up at `dist/img`. All bundle files are also built into `dist`. E.g. the CSS ends up at something like `app.hash.css`.

Now, in the HTML files I can do `img/filename.ext` and it works. But in the CSS files, I am not able to correctly load the `url()`.

For example, in `component.css`, `url('img/filename.ext')` would not be found. If I do `url('../../../public/img/filename.ext')`, WebPack finds the file but the URL is not correctly built, it ends up having the whole path through `src` which is of course not found in the `dist` folder.

Here is the relevant part of my config. I've set it up for both the WebPack dev server and for prod build.

```
var ENV = process.env.npm_lifecycle_event;
var isProd = ENV === 'build';

module.exports = function makeWebPackConfig () {
  var config = {};

  config.entry = {
    app: './src/app/app.js'
  };

  config.output = {
    path: __dirname + '/dist',
    publicPath: isProd ? '/' : 'http://localhost:8080/',
    filename: isProd ? '[name].[hash].js' : '[name].bundle.js',
    chunkFilename: isProd ? '[name].[hash].js' : '[name].bundle.js'
  };

  config.module = {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.html$/,
      loader: 'raw'
    },
    {
      test: /\.css$/,
      loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css?sourceMap!postcss')
    },
    {
      test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|otf)$/,
      loader: 'file?name=[path][name].[ext]'
    }]
  }

  config.plugins = [];
  config.plugins.push(
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/public/index.html',
      inject: 'body'
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].[hash].css', { disable: !isProd })
  )

  if (isProd) {
    config.plugins.push(
      new CopyWebpackPlugin([{
        from: __dirname + '/src/public'
      }])
    )
  }

  config.devServer = {
    outputPath: path.join(__dirname, 'app'),
    contentBase: './src/public',
    stats: 'minimal'
  };

  return config;
}();
```

Which part of all the paths in the setup is causing this?

**E.** I should add that in this case I do not have control over the fact that the files will be copied from the public folder in this way.